# How to filter a dataframe using only base R

Tags: r, datetime, data-manipulation

I'm using a linked server that won't let me download new R packages (meaning I can only use base R).  I know how to filter and select using `dplyr` and `tidyverse` but how can I select only rows for a new `data.frame` (`students.bio`) that meet the condition of `students%subject == "Biology"`? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
students.bio <- students[which(students$subject == "Biology"), ]
students.bio <- Filter(students$subject == "Biology", students)
```

The first results in an empty df and the second says it can't find a function in the first argument.

I'm new to R so appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `students[students$subject == "Biology", ]` or `subset(students, subject == "Biology")`

Comment: Maybe the string `students$subject` has no `"Biology"` in it Maybe it has `" Biology "` or different formats of Biology. I guess you should take that into consideration

Comment: As an aside, `Filter` needs a function as the first argument, like `Filter(function(x) x>=6, 1:10)`. It also won't work nicely on `data.frames` to subset rows as it was built for vectors, and will actually subset columns from a `data.frame` - `Filter(function(x) any(x>=6), data.frame(a=1:10,b=rep(0,10)))` for instance.